# Is UIElement.RenderTransform used by TransformToAncestor?

Tags: c#, wpf, rendertransform

When a TransformToAncestor is called what Matrices are used to build up the resultant GeneralTransform?  When step into the pdb all I see is a TransformField with a signature like:

```
private static readonly UncommonField<Transform> TransformField = new UncommonField<Transform>();
```

being used in the resultant GeneralTransform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing beats Reflector. Especially while it's still free ;)

The code is hairy enough but can be followed. Basically it walks up the visual tree and groups the transforms but the entire thing is much more complicated and I never really had an interest to dig that deep into it. Look into Visual.TrySimpleTransformToAncestor for the gory details.

To answer the question, UIElement is never used explicitly of course; the transform is retrieved through an Effect (the UncommonField you mentioned), so I'm guessing that transforms in general are applied as effects, hence you can get them through this shortcut from anywhere, but that's just infrastructure and implementation details and I'm most likely wrong :)

Comment: How would you access this "Effect"?

Comment: Well, it's the VisualEffect property on Visual, at least in theory. However, an important piece of the answer is the internal function Effect.CoerceToUnitSpaceGeneralTransform, which I think might have the role of returning the transform _after_ any effect is applied... not really sure of anything after that though :)

Comment: Anything more is deeply internal to WPF and not really accessible to the outside world unless you duplicate all the code - maybe if you have a _specific_ reason why it interests you, this conversation could be more productive? :)

Comment: I'm using OnRender for an System.Windows.Controls.Image derived class to dynamically (based on zoom level and clip rectangle) show really large images.  I have a scenario where an addition visual is injected into the rendering tree and TransformToAncestor returns me an incorrect GeneralTransform.  After I zoom then I get the correct result.  I'm trying to figure out why I keep getting the bad result.

Comment: I've tried a variety of UpdateLayouts at different tree levels and nothing seems to have an effect.

Comment: Ouch. Well that seems well above my level of expertise, I'd be mostly guessing from here on - actually already did that quite a bit. Sorry.

Comment: I've been trying to understand how the transforms are accumulated so I can figure out how to force TransformToAncestor to give me a consistently good result.

Comment: So have you tried TransformToVisual instead of ToAncestor? There's quite a bit extra going on there, although it's on the same lines.

Comment: Also, it should be noted TrySimpleTransformToAncestor returns false in some conditions, in which case the return value of TransformToAncestor is set to the default Transform. And the most important condition seems to be... whether any of the Effects of ancestor up to the target ancestor have a transform which is affine - but I gotta call it quits, it's quite late and the code just dances before my eyes.

Comment: TransformToVisual gets the same result.